# Small multiples: how to add axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, axis

Has anybody an idea how to add a y-axis to this example below?  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e1192fe405703d8321a5187350910e08

The example shows how to generate multiple charts at once with dynamically calculated yScale for each data series. But how to add yAxis to each chart using local yScale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example you linked, the only thing you need is to set the local variable for each SVG:

```
axis.set(this, d3.axisRight(ty).ticks(3));
```

Here, I'm using `ticks(3)` because we don't have too much vertical space there, and the `ty` is the scale created for each SVG. Then, you later use that local variable as:

```
svg.each(function(){
    axis.get(this)(d3.select(this)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)"));
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/7ce71db8470c75940feed0d64b3f1f25/fb38b0867f434268e254f08e469cf38113179472

---

PS: Pay attention to the fact that here I'm using...

```
axisGenerator(groupSelection)
```

... instead of the way more traditional pattern of...

```
groupSelection.call(axisGenerator)
```

... because we cannot get `this` with the traditional pattern. For using the traditional patter without the `each` method, you'd need a weird auxiliary function, like:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
    .call(generateAxis);

function generateAxis(selection) {
    selection.call(axis.get(selection.node()));
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually did two mistakes. First, I tried "call" method with anonymous function to call axis, and second, I have more complex data structure and pointing to "this" from a deeper level axis.set(this, d3.axisRight(ty).ticks(3)); was an incorrect reference - changing "this" to "this.parentNode" and using "svg.each" method solved my problem :) Thanks once again!